# Is There A Way To Set A Fields Default Value to Max + 1 in Mysql phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm adding a field to my table called "room_num".  Basically upon insert I'd like to set the default value of the room_num to be the max value of the last room_num + 1.  Obviously I'd use auto-increment if this table applied to only one user but, it will apply to many so I have a running unique index as well as a unique field user_index.

I could run a query based on the user_index and return the max for "room_num" but, since I'm already here, is there a way to make the default value some sort of function?

So, for example my table looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| index |  room_num   |  title  |  user_index |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 0     | 0           | Patio   | 10          |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 1     + 1           | Dining  | 10          |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 2     + 0           | Bar     | 15          |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 3     + 2           | Dining  | 10          |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

So, now I want the default value for room_num of my next insert for user_index 15 to default to max room_num (0) + 1 (which in this case would be 1).  But, I'd like to take care of this here:

[image]

Rather than querying for it in my application first and THEN inserting the record and in essence making two database connections.

Is this possible?

Comment: // Off topic - How do you make those nice tables?

Comment: No, you can't do it like that, within the `DEFAULT` value of the column. What you can do is create a `BEFORE/AFTER INSERT` trigger that will do the calculations and update the column value. Also, whenever you use PHPMyAdmin a kitten dies :/

Comment: @N.B. What do you recommend instead of PHPMyAdmin? Can't be killing kittens now, can we!

Comment: SQLYog, MySQL Workbench, anything that doesn't require you to install a PHP script (full of security holes) on your server.

Comment: @Jleagle plus minus and pipes!

Comment: Oh, I just presumed you used a tool to make the layout for you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (title, user_index, room_num)
  SELECT 'MyTitle', 10, COALESCE((MAX(room_num) + 1), 1)
  FROM   myTable
  WHERE  user_index = 10
```

Obviously, from your application you would just replace `'MyTitle'` and the instances of `10` with your desired title and proper user_index.

**Note: Based on my five minutes with Google, I don't think `INSERT...SELECT` is an atomic operation. So, you'll probably want to wrap this in a transaction or table lock/unlock to prevent race conditions.**

Comment: Triggers (with InnoDB) **is** the best way to go around the problem rather than doing logic in the table definition.